# Query without type using spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using the spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 2.2.13.RELEASE to fetch data from an external elasticsearch 6.7.2. However I have limited access to this elasticsearch, only allowing me to use the _search for the indexes.

That's my entity:

```
@Document(indexName = "funds_v1", createIndex = false, type = "doc")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Funds {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String issuerId;
    private String strategyShortName;
}
```

When I call the method findAll() from the repository in the logs it displays that:
**curl -iX POST 'https://{host}:443/es/funds_v1/doc/_search?rest_total_hits_as_int=true&typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512' -d '{"size":0,"query":{"match_all":{"boost":1.0}}}'**

however I don't want that **/doc** and if I just remove the type from the Annotation @Document it will be replaced to the simple name of the class.